# What to use in creating Json Web service in Zend framework for Android/Iphone application

Tags: json, zend-framework

I using Zend Framework for Developing my web application , I want to create a Web services for  an Android application , the content type will be JSON.

what is the best way to create this webservice ? 
is it a Controller and this Controller will extend the Action controller

```
class ApiController extends Frontend_Controller_Action
```

or to use `Zend_Json_Server`  .
I am little confused , what the zend Json Server will help better than ApiController  ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Read about Zend_Rest_Controller. Use it instead of Zend_Controller_Action. It very simple.
Zend_Rest_Controller is just an abstract controller with a list of predefined Actions that you should implement in your Controllers. Short example, I used it like Index Controller in Api module:

```
class Api_IndexController extends Zend_Rest_Controller 
{
    public function init()
    {
        $bootstrap = $this->getInvokeArg('bootstrap');
        $this->_helper->layout->disableLayout();
        $this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender(TRUE);
        $this->_helper->AjaxContext()
                ->addActionContext('get','json')
                ->addActionContext('post','json')
                ->addActionContext('new','json')
                ->addActionContext('edit','json')
                ->addActionContext('put','json')
                ->addActionContext('delete','json')
                ->initContext('json');
     }

     public function indexAction()
     {
         $method = $this->getRequest()->getParam('method');
         $response = new StdClass();
         $response->status = 1;

         if($method != null){
             $response->method = $method;
             switch ($method) {
                case 'category':
                 ...
                break;
                case 'products':
                 ...
                break;
                default:
                $response->error = "Method '" . $response->method . "' not exist!!!";
             }
         }

         $content = $this->_helper->json($response);
         $this->sendResponse($content);
     }

     private function sendResponse($content){
        $this->getResponse()
           ->setHeader('Content-Type', 'json')
           ->setBody($content)
           ->sendResponse();
        exit;
     }

     public function getAction()
     {}

     public function postAction()
     {}

     public function putAction()
     {}

     public function deleteAction()
     {}
}
```

Comment: thanks, shall i create one Rest Controller for my application or to create more than one controller , depends on the project

Comment: Welcome! In my project I use one controller. But my project very simple, and created for my own needs. You can create much controllers as you need.

Comment: But what if I want to use additional actions ? like registerAction or something like this

Comment: I use only one action and in index action check get parameter 'method'

Comment: $method = $this->getRequest()->getParam('method');